# Robot Framework Python - Unable to access the modal Input box

Tags: python, selenium, modal-dialog, robotframework

i wrote a robot Framework code to access an input box on Modal which open on a button click , but it open the model and says "input box" is not interactable . there is no iframe enclosing the Modal box and Modal box enclosed by div which only has class attriute.

Below is the code i wrote.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Dialogs
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${browser}  Chrome
${url}    abc
${passwordmgt}  admin

*** Test Cases ***
OpenBrowserToCheck
    Selenium2Library.Open Browser  ${url}   ${browser}
GetInputFromUser
    [Documentation]    User to enter the Actual and Copied filename
    Get_UserNamePassword


*** Keywords ***
Get_UserNamePassword
    ${dbname} = Get Value From User     Input user name default

    Selenium2Library.Click Element  xpath://button[contains(., "Backup") and @data-db='${dbname}']
    click element  xpath://div[@class='modal-dialog']
    Selenium2Library.click element  xpath://div[@class='modal-dialog']//form[@id='form_backup_db']//div[@class='modal-body']//div[@class='form-group row']//div[@class='col-md-8 input-group']//input
```

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DolpA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using two options on the the element you want to click:

```
 1. Click Button    xpath=element_xpath
 2. Press Keys      xpath=element_xpath         //13
```

Comment: but when i give my xpath expression it says element not interactable. Is it because of pop up

Comment: if you have pop Handle that with Alert kw before you proceed.

Comment: How did you handled it?

Comment: 'Examples:

Handle Alert   # Accept alert.
Handle Alert action=DISMISS  # Dismiss alert.
Handle Alert timeout=10 s  # Use custom timeout and accept alert.
Handle Alert DISMISS 1 min # Use custom timeout and dismiss alert.
${message} = Handle Alert  # Accept alert and get its message.
${message} = Handle Alert LEAVE # Leave alert open and get its message.'

Use Link - https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Handle%20Alert

Answer (score 0):

To interact with modal we can use TAB keys to set the focus to that modal and then interacting with that modal, in my case this way worked for me.

```
To Interact With Modal
# button to trigger modal popup

    Click Button    ${modalTrigger}
    # in my case let's suppose the input text field is will be on focus after pressing TAB two times

    Press Keys    NONE    TAB
    Press Keys    NONE    TAB
    Input Text    locator    text

    # to move to submit button

    Press Keys    NONE    TAB
    Press Keys    NONE    SPACE
```